# Protect JSON data passing it to the front end in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, api, express

I'm developing an e-commerce app using NodeJs, Express and MongoDB. As endpoints i have some JSON objects for the front end. My idea was passing these data to the front end and render on client side usign something like React for create the UI, but actually i think can be insecure the passage of JSON object to the front end like an API (an attacker can take some data and redirect on a fake website), an other idea can be render on server side but my server could be overloaded. There is a solution for passing these objects or render an HTML page on server side and pass that to the client (at this point react will complete the UI)?
This is a graph of my (insecure) idea

[image: This is a graph of my idea]

Is possible to secure this data so passing it not like an API but as a web page?

Comment: *"an attacker can take some data and redirect on a fake website"* –What exactly do you mean by this? That attackers could steal your JSON data and then put it on a fake replica of your site?

Answer (score 1):

One way is to secure your API with JWT tokens. https://jwt.io/

The other way you mentioned before is to use server side HTML rendering .
Your server will handle the data so you are not sending data with JSON but with HTML formated to your needs. (but still there is no protection at this)

Answer (score 0):

Another good approach is use SSR Server Side Rendering, all logic etc will be proccessed in server side and result html will be deliver to its clients.

There are two main projects of SSR

https://www.gatsbyjs.com/

and

https://nextjs.org/

Comment: So if the client unlog and login as another user, it must refresh the page ? Bad idea...

Comment: You dont think so?

Comment: Yep, the front end is SPA, so you don't have to need to refresh. But the ssr rendering is use on entering on the website... In the case I explained, login, logout, login with another user, this way could not fit....

Comment: Oh may this solution not fit, but so you really may consider use jwt like others answers are pointing to

Comment: Yes I'm agree with this

Comment: Yeah i can use handlebars for render in server side, but at this point my server will be too overloaded, i can try to render a lightweight page on server and use react client-side for the rest. Actually i'm using JWT, but an attacker can log in and the server will give the token to him....